# VBA: Only visible cells are getting pasted

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I am trying to copy backend data from a chart in a slide and pasting it to an excel. The problem is only visible column(s) are getting pasted. On research I found out that while copying everything including hidden cells are indeed copied but for some reason only visible cells can be pasted. So I am struggling to find a way to paste everything. There is an option for unhiding columns before copying, but because any change in embedded excel in chart tends to stay, so trying to avoid that.

Also it seems only *.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll* works with ppt chartdata. *.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats*; *.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues* and others don't work.

Any help is much appreciated.

Code:

```
Dim rng As Excel.Range
Set rng = chtdat.Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1:Z17") 'Col C to G is hidden
'Have tried the following: UsedRange, CurrentRegion
 rng.Copy
        
 On Error Resume Next
    chtdat.Workbook.Close , False
 On Error GoTo 0
          
          If QCWbk.Sheets("QC-Sheet").Range("B3") = "" Then
          
             'QCWbk.Sheets("QC-Sheet").Range("B2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
             'QCWbk.Sheets("QC-Sheet").Range("B2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
             
             'QCWbk.Sheets("QC-Sheet").Range("B2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
              QCWbk.Sheets("QC-Sheet").Range("CheckThis").Sort key1:=QCWbk.Sheets("QC-Sheet").Range("B2:B17"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
             
             QCWbk.Save
             QCWbk.Close
             
          Else
```

Answer (score 0):

Try copy method, it will copy all value including hidden column, although I did not test for different workbook, it shall be working

```
Sheet1.Range("D5:F5").Copy Sheet1.Range("M2:O2")
```

If you only want copy visible cell, then including special cell function will work

```
Sheet1.Range("D5:F5").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy  Sheet1.Range("M2:O2")
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but my issue is that the hidden columns when pasted aren't getting pasted although document says when copying - hidden columns are indeed copied.

Comment: Without showing your example for the data, I can't really tell what is your issue. The above 2 formula work 100% all the time, unless your if function does not set correctly.